# My Wi-Fi keeps turning off after setting up Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, hyper-v-manager

So i was trying to set up a linux Virtual Machine in Hyper-V, I added a Virtual Switch in Hyper-V and then my internet shutoff i knew that was going to happen because it had a warning before. But i waited for 10 minutes even tried to reconnect to the internet but it still didnt work. So i removed the Virtual Switch from Hyper-V wifi connected and everything was fine.

But a bit after I went to google.com and it first said "The site can't be reached" sometimes "The connection was interupted" and if you wait a couple of seconds it says "No Internet" but on the windows taskbar it said "Connected, Secured". I havent gotten any problem like this before. Can you help me?

P.S. To fix this i need to turn off the internet andd connect to it back again through the windows taskbar. This happens every 10-20 minutes.

Comment: Can you provide us the exact warning you received?

Comment: A hyper-v virtual switch is a software layer in between your internet and pc such that it can share internet to the hyper-v. Its pretty normal that your internet disconnects when you add it, given that the direct connection, internet -> pc has to be broken in order to place something in between. Once that is done, you should be able to re-establish your internet just as before, but may help to reboot after you add the hyper-v switch.

Comment: Please describe in greater detail how you added the VSwitch, how it was configured and what you needed it for. For regular internet access, Hyper-V already comes with a preconfigured VSwitch with NAT.

Comment: If your Host machine uses WiFi, can you just use the Default Hyper-V switch?  That works here. Perhaps remove Hyper-V (Programs and Features), restart and re-enable Hyper-V. This should reset it.

Answer (score 0):

A friend was running into the same issue and this resource helped us solve the problem of the WiFi disconnecting. I hope sharing resources is acceptable as I did not figure this out on my own, this is what I used. I am quoting a gentleman named Micheal on the topic Hyper V disconnects wifi

“For your need, we could utilize ICS in the Hyper-network deployment for your VMs connection, please refer to the following article demonstrated sharing network connection with ICS in Hyper-V.

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/share-an-ethernet-or-wireless-network-connection-with-hyper-v-in-windows-10/

http://www.mustbegeek.com/configure-hyper-v-virtual-machine-with-internet-connection/

Meanwhile, here're the similar situation that Linux-based VM connect to the network via wifi as yours for your reference. Hope this helps.

[Connecting a Hyper-V VM (Linux based) to the internet via wifi - No wifi appears to connect to in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/696717/connecting-a-hyper-v-vm-linux-based-to-the-internet-via-wifi-no-wifi-appears)

[How do I setup a working Wifi/Internet connection on Windows 10 hyper-v?](https://superuser.com/questions/1403016/how-do-i-setup-a-working-wifi-internet-connection-on-windows-10-hyper-v)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2015/02/02/hyper-v-and-wireless-networking/ “

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.